# How do you remove an li with specific text?

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-lists

Thanks for taking the time to read this.

I need to remove the list item that contains "Log In". The problem is that once logged in the list items change and I can't remove them by the order they are displayed in the list. I also cannot just delete the html or give any of the list items additional Ids or classes. I can add css and javascript though that does interact with the page.

Is there a way to remove only the list item that contains "Log In" within the li and anchor tags?

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav" id="navLinks">
    <li class="list-group-item">
        <a href="/">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li class="list-group-item">
        <a href="/postings/search">Search</a>
    </li>
    <li class="list-group-item">
        <a href="/user/new">Create Account</a>
    </li>
    <li class="list-group-item">
        <a href="/login">Log In</a>
    </li>
    <li class="list-group-item">
        <a href="/help">Help</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you want to show the login element if the user is not logged in, if they are then you will hide it. Since you have control over the CSS, add a helper class `.hide` that sets display property to `display: none;`.

Then when you have a user logged in, you run a conditional in JS to check the `textContent` of the ***list-items*** ***(children[0])***, which will be the `a` tag. Check the userLoggin status and if both natch add the class. I also added `let userLoggedIn = true;` as a parameter to the function to check if this is also true or not allowing you to control whether the class is added depending on whether user is logged in or not.

You can query the `list-group-item` using  `document.querySelectorAll('#navLinks .list-group-item');` then iterate over the nodeList and use a conditional to search the first childs `textContent` using `item.children[0].textContent === 'Log In'`, if this conditional returns true then and ***user is logged in*** add a css class to hide the element.

```js
const listItems = document.querySelectorAll('#navLinks .list-group-item')
const listItems2 = document.querySelectorAll('#navLinks2 .list-group-item')

function hideItem(el, bool) {
  el.forEach(item => 
     item.children[0].textContent === 'Log In' && bool === true ?
       item.classList.add('hide') : 
       item.classList.remove('hide')
  )
}

let userLoggedIn = true
let userLoggedIn2 = false
hideItem(listItems, userLoggedIn)
hideItem(listItems2, userLoggedIn2)
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<h2>user is logged in</h2>
<ul class="nav navbar-nav" id="navLinks">
  <li class="list-group-item">
    <a href="/">Home</a>
  </li>
  <li class="list-group-item">
    <a href="/postings/search">Search</a>
  </li>
  <li class="list-group-item">
    <a href="/user/new">Create Account</a>
  </li>
  <li class="list-group-item">
    <a href="/login">Log In</a>
  </li>
  <li class="list-group-item">
    <a href="/help">Help</a>
  </li>
</ul>
<h2>user is NOT logged in</h2>
<ul class="nav navbar-nav" id="navLinks2">
  <li class="list-group-item">
    <a href="/">Home</a>
  </li>
  <li class="list-group-item">
    <a href="/postings/search">Search</a>
  </li>
  <li class="list-group-item">
    <a href="/user/new">Create Account</a>
  </li>
  <li class="list-group-item">
    <a href="/login">Log In</a>
  </li>
  <li class="list-group-item">
    <a href="/help">Help</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Dale, thank you! Your first answer prior to your edit actually worked perfectly. I have small sections I can add styles and scripts. However, I am clueless on how to manipulate items outside of a defined Id or given class.  I know how to manipulate list items by order but when the user logs in, more list items appear. Hiding the Log in is perfect because in the custom navigation I have access to, I am able to provide two different login links, one to perspective users, and another for current users. I've had people frustrated & create new accounts. Problem is eliminated. I have much to learn!

Comment: Glad to help out and if your not continuously learning, then IMHO, you're not working ;) Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

If the Login item is always the fourth, you can do it by adding the next js:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.list-group-item')[3].remove()
```

That does not require an interaction with the user and you can add it in any function you want.